# New entities have not yet received database-generated key values (while updating EF Record)

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, generics

Why does EF update need to have database generated code in order to update record.
The same process in NH does not database generated code.
I have a generic Base service in the update function ,I convert **`Poco`** object to **`entity table type object`** and call the update function of generic repository base call

```
    T model = Mapper.Map<M, T>(entity);
    Entity.Update( model);
```

here is my update function

```
   this.ObjectSet.Attach(NewEntity);          
   _Context.ObjectContext.Entry(NewEntity).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
   _Context.SaveChanges();
```

when i try to update state of entity type object EF throghs errors.
**new entities  have not yet received database-generated key values **

when i modify and the service base and select object from database in current database connection it compile update record without error

update service

```
 T model = Mapper.Map<M, T>(entity);
 T tEntity = Entity.GetSingle(Entity.SearchFilters(model));
 Entity.Update(tEntity, model);
```

updated generic repository base code.

```
this.ObjectSet.Attach(entity);
_Context.ObjectContext.Entry(entity).CurrentValues.SetValues(NewEntity);     _Context.ObjectContext.Entry(entity).State =System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
_Context.SaveChanges();
```

**My Question is :**

**Why Entity framework need database generated Code for updating entity.**

**IS there a to update entity without selecting is from database because i new that record exist in database ?**

Thanks

Comment: unless you're still using EF 4, please remove the ObjectContext/ ObjectSet calls, EF5 replaced these by DbContext

Comment: ObjectSet is Property of DbSet<T> type

Comment: Much more is unclear. What is `ObjectContext`? Where/how is this code embedded? What is the *full* exception message? I don't think you picked the relevant part form it. What is the lifespan of your context? Where does `NewEntity` come from?